# PHP cURL CURLOPT_FILE is empty after curl_exec()

Tags: php, curl, download, wget

I am working on a script for downloading and scanning particular webpage elements I am trying to download this example page with PHP cURL:

http://www.jetbull.com/Deposit

However, every time I attempt the curl_exec() the output file is empty. Would anyone know why this is or be able to lead me on the path to fixing this?

I am easily able to use pretty much any other URL in this function and this won't happen.

```
function download_page($url, $out_file = "body.txt") {

    $fp = fopen($out_file, "w");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    curl_exec($ch);
    fclose($fp);
    $details = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $details;
}

$url = "http://www.jetbull.com/Deposit";
download_page($url);
```

I am running PHP 5.2.6 inside a nix environment. 
I can see clearly the page will return a 307, though I am unsure as to why a redirect isn't followed (if that is indeed the problem).

In Firefox, this page is retrieved fine, with a reported HTTP 200.
Is the server responding in some non-standard fashion that cURL isn't handling, or is cURL not following the redirect properly, else am I doing something else just plain silly?

Any help at all for information on how to fix this or to lead me down the path would be very appreciated!

Comment: `$data = curl_exec($ch); return $data;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this option

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

Comment: Okay..? This will persist the cookies to a file, what does this achieve in terms of being able to get the body?

Comment: Your script return this error "curl Maximum (20) redirects followed" because you don't use cookie

Answer (score 0):

Remove this option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: You can use CURLOPT_FILE and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER together, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925052/6036546).