# php Curl confilict CURLOPT_FILE and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER in docker

Tags: php, docker

When I using curl with  `CURLOPT_FILE` and  `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option, file is empty, without any curl error:

```
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'ccc.text');

curl_exec($ch);
```

Curl error: No error

```
echo curl_strerror(curl_errno($ch)); //No error
```

By remove `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` result is true.

I test it in php 5.6 & 7.2 with apache and php-fpm 7.2 with nginx in docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` needs be set to `true` *before* setting `CURLOPT_FILE` to the file handle.

Compare with [this comment in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082):

> It appears that setting CURLOPT_FILE before setting
> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER doesn't work, presumably because CURLOPT_FILE
> depends on CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER being set.

So try different a order:

```
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'wb');
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'ccc.text');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

See also these comments in the PHP manual:
[CURLOPT_FILE to STDOUT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#58074) and [fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#92522) for additional information on how to restore output to STDOUT and that the file pointer/stream handle needs to be closed after curl finished.

Comment: The order als works when setting multiple options in an array, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER comes first, then CURLOPT_FILE and then it works. When CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set after CURLOPT_FILE, the file won't get the response body, it will be returned by curl_exec() as string (instead bool status).